# Setup launch.json file for Flutter web using local Flutter version

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have installed Flutter in my mac inside my root folder: `/[root]/flutter` and I use it on project A.

Now I need to use a different version of Flutter for project B (flutter web), so I cloned Flutter inside project B's root directory.
I know that to run it, I have to launch `./flutter/bin/flutter run` but how can I setup `launch.json` for VScode?

Here is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Web",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "deviceId": "chrome",
      "args": [
        ??
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I think that if I use it, then it will use the standard Flutter in my mac root and not the Flutter inside the project folder.
How can I edit the launch in a way that if I click on the play button in VScode then it will run `./flutter/bin/flutter run`?

I'm not interested to use tools like FVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open command palette, enter `Preferences: Open User Settings`.

Search `Flutter Sdk Paths`. Add additional flutter sdk from there.

Open flutter project. Do `Flutter: Change SDK` in the command palette.